# UITableview height changes after viewdidappear called for the second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a TableView

[image: First Tab with table view]

With these constraints set

[image: constraints]

Whenever I go to "Select Folder" tab and comeback again to "All Files", the tableView height is increased by 49 and the toolbar having "Delete" button disappears as it is pushed down further

[image: tableview height increased]

I fail to understand how to resolve this issue. I did many things like:

1. Change priority of constraints to make sure that table bottom has higher priority
2. Delete the table and add new one
3. Delete the toolbar, pin the table bottom to navigation bar.

None of the above worked. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try after set Width & Height constrains of tableView??

Comment: Yes I did, I set UITableView height constraint to <=410, it did not worked. The UITableView height after the second calling of viewdidappear scales to 435

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but deleting the whole view and recreating from start with the "same constraints" did solve this issue.

I am attributing this to Xcode 5.1.1 bug

Unless someone has a more better explanation I will mark that as accepted answer.